# Are my associations causing an undefined method for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these model and controller code:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :user_id
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :owned_items, class_name: "Item"
end

class ItemsController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @items = Item.search(params[:search]).approved.page(params[:page])
 end
end
```

Typing `Item.owner.username` into ruby console returns the `Item` owner's username, but when calling the following view code outside of a loop in my view,

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
 ...
 ...
 <div class="posted-to lightgrey">Posted by <a href=""><%= link_to item.owner.username, profile_path(item.owner.username) %></a></div>
<% end %>
```

It results in an `undefined method 'username' for nil:NilClass` error. Why is this?

Comment: You have, apparently, one or more `Items` without an `Owner`.

Comment: looks like that was it. i was running off seed data i created before changing the data model.

Comment: make this comment into an answer and i can give you points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, apparently, one or more `Items` without an `Owner`.